# Signing iOS app with someone else's developer certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am developing an app with my friend and I need to sign with his identity for testing push notification system. Here is what we did:

- I've sent my UDID to him, he added my UDID to his devices
- He created a new provisioning profile for our bundle ID, including my UDID for use with his developer certificate
- He sent the provisioning profile to me.
- I've added provisioning profile to my device and Xcode.
- He exported his developer certificate (with private key) in Keychain access and sent it to me
- I've imported his certificate successfully
- I've selected the provisioning profile that he sent at Xcode

I've tried to run the app and it said that no valid signing identities were found for that provisioning profile. Then I've tried to type the `p12` file into the certificate by clicking `Other` (Xcode couldn't find any certificate valid for that provisioning profile by itself) but it couldn't sign:

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities
(i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile
specified in your build settings (“tanisalim”) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'
```

Here is my project configuration:

[image]

How can I codesign the app with my friend's certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, if you're collaborating during development then your friend should add you to his account as a developer and add your certificate to the development provisioning profile.

To do this he needs to invite you to his developer account, then you create your certificate. [See Apple's App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

However, if you just want to use his identity, I would instead open his p12 file which will import it into your keychain. I don't think typing the path p12 into the Code Signing Identity works.

Make sure you've got the [WWDR certificate installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057241/iphone-what-the-heck-is-a-wwdr-intermediate-certificate), check the app bundleID matches that of the the provisioning profile, restart Xcode for good measure and *then* you *should* be able to select his code signing identity and sign your app.

Comment: how can he invite me to his developer account? I couldn't find information regarding that, other than company accounts (which aren't our case). I want to use his identity, I've opened the p12 file that he exported but still I can't sign using that certificate.

Comment: I've found the problem. the developer certificate did not contain the private key. even when I told him to send me the cert with private key from keychain access, he was selecting the certificate only, assuming the private key was also being exported. after a bit research (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965723/811405) I've understood that one should select both the certificate and the private key together explicitly as in the screenshot given at that answer. keychain access shows like private key is in the certificate, which leads to great confusion.

Comment: If your friend is enrolled as an individual and not as an organization, he can't invite you. See [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingAccounts/ManagingAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH24-SW1] (Apple's guide), especially under "Choose to Enroll as an Individual or an Organization”.